# Reading CSV file and storing in HASHMAP

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons, opencsv

I am trying to **read CSV file** and keep Key Value pair in a **HASHMAP**
Both **CSV** or **Apache commons** are considered

```
HashMap<String, Student>
```

Where key will store Student roll no in String and Student has corresponding data in its **POJO** like roll no, student name, course

*Now in CSV I have following headers : Year(Joining data), Roll no, student name, Course*

**Two ways:**

1. With headers to check since I already know which Column values I want but need to check for column number
2. Without headers I already know specifically at which column number my headers
   are placed therefore I removed it already

First I tried without headers

```
Map<String, Student> map =new HashMap<String, Student>(); 
        Student student=new Student();
     try {

            // Create an object of filereader
            // class with CSV file as a parameter.
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\hpadmin\\ExcelDocuments\\1_Roll_spec.csv");

            // create csvReader object passing
            // file reader as a parameter
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(filereader,',', '\'', 1);
            String[] nextRecord;

            // we are going to read data line by line
            while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

                student.setRoll_No(nextRecord[1]);
                student.setStudentName(nextRecord[2]);
                map.put(nextRecord[1], student);
                nextRecord=null;
            }

            Set<Map.Entry<String, Student>> set = map.entrySet();

            for (Map.Entry<String, Student> me : set) {
                  System.out.println(" Roll No : "+ me.getValue().getRoll_No()+" Student Name :"+me.getValue().getStudentName());

                }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I got only the last address also equals to the number of records also I don't have any idea to do with headers and read according to header name

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? HINT: You override the Student object in every Iteration. Create the Student object inside of your loop

Comment: BTW `nextRecord=null;` is not needed

Comment: @Jens Okay solved student object should be created for every record that was silly. But still struggling how do I recognize the headers

Comment: @Jens what If in CSV I have header for roll no and student name is at column 1 and 4 respectively then we cannot hard code nextRecord[1] and nextRecord[2] to be precise where your headers are exactly in csv file